# update the session field in database

Tags: php, sql, database, types, field

I have a database. I had created a a table containing only one row in DB if it wasn't constructed before.

Why it has only 1 row is that I just use it to keep some info.

There is a field of `TYPE NVARCHAR(100)` which I want to use it to **store session id**, 
and here comes the headache for me:

It seems that I can't even properly INSERT(I use `phpmyadmin` to check and it's blank) and UPDATE(syntax error...) it with a session id obtained from `session_id()`, which is returned as a `string`.

Here is the portion of my code relating to my action:

```
//uamip,uamport is in URL;I use $_GET[]

$_SESSION[uamport] = $_GET['uamport'];

$_SESSION[uamip] = $_GET['uamip'];

**$_SESSION[sid] = session_id();**

//construct

$sql="CREATE TABLE trans_vector(

        `index` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        `sid` NVARCHAR(100),
        `uamip` CHAR(15),
        `uamport` INT,
        PRIMARY KEY (`index`)
      )" ;

mysql_query($sql);

//insert(first time, so not constructed)

$sql="INSERT INTO trans_vector (sid,uamip,uamport) VALUES(

       '$_SESSION[sid]',
       '$_SESSION[myuamip]',
       '$_SESSION[myuamport]'
     )";

mysql_query($sql);

//update(from 2nd time and later, table exists, so I want to update the sid part)

$sql="UPDATE trans_vector SET sid="**.**$_SESSION[sid];

mysql_query($sql)
```

Now, when I use phpmyadmin to check the `sid field` after `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, **It is blank**;

But if I do this:

```
$vector=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT TABLES LIKE 'trans_vector'"));
```

and `echo $vector[sid]` ,then it's printed on webpage.

**Another question is**:

With the `UPDATE` statement above, I always get such error:

"Unknown column xxxxxx....(some session id returned, it seems it always translate it **first** and put it in the SQL statement, ** treating it as a column NAME** that's not what I want!)"

I tried some TYPE in CREATE statement, and also lots of syntax of the UPDATE statement(everything!!!) but it always give this error.

I am dealing trouble with `'` and string representation containing a variable where the latter's value is actually what I want... and maybe the problem arise from type in CREATE and string representation in `UPDATE` statement?

Should `CAST()` statement helpful for me?

Wish you can help me deal with this...and probably list some real reference of such issue in `PHP`?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO trans_vector (`sid`, `uamip`, `uamport`) VALUES(

       '".$_SESSION["sid"]."',
       '".$_SESSION["myuamip"]."',
       '".$_SESSION["myuamport"]."'
     )";
```

this should solve at least some warnings, if not errors.

and for update...

```
$update = "UPDATE trans_vector SET `sid`='".$_SESSION["sid"]."';";
```

Notes about your code: 
Array values have to be put into the string with operator '.' and cannot be inserted directly. Array indexes must be strings (note the ") or integers.

Column names should have `` around them. To insert a string with SQL, you have to put string into ''s, so the parser knows what is string and what column name. Without ''s parser is assuming you are stating a column.

and for mysql_escape_string, I assumed you handle that before storing data to sessions. Without those, you might can get unwanted SQL injections. And in case you did not do that, you can either do that (before you create queries):

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value)
    $_SESSION[$key] = mysql_escape_string($value);
```

or manually escape strings when you create a query.

Comment: may I ask several question:

1.the index of array-variable should be quoted by " or ' ? or by concerning "be a string", both is available case by case?

2.can you explain for me what things like '".$_SESSION["sid"]."' are worked out by php executor cause I still couldn't figure it out completely;why is the outest two 's needed? and how is it reasonable to put two [dot]'s just around the variable?

3. what does backtick working as? how does it work when used to quote [table_name] ?

4. sql statement like $sql="[bla's]" must have ; at the end of [bla's]? but SELECT and SHOW don't? what is it?

Comment: 1. Both, ' and " indexing works fine
2. in SQL queries: you usually start with ", to begin a php string. this makes it easy to use ' as SQL string. now, we need ' to begin SQL string, " to end php string, . to add something to string, . to add string, " to start string, ' to end SQL string;
3. i THINK you're asking why you need indexing with " or '. It's because if you don't specify as string, php will check for constants, which are without $.
4. Technically you don't need ; in SQL query. But it's a nice practice to end all queries with ; as well.

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As for the update statement, it’s clear that there are apostrophes missing. You always need apostrophes, when you want to insert a string value into the database. Moreover, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string`.
However, I think standard `mysql` is deprecated and has been removed in newer versions of PHP in favor of MySQLi and PDO. Thus you should switch to MySQLi or PDO soon.

You should also use apostrophes when referencing values within `$_SESSION`. Otherwise PHP will try to find a constanst with the name `sid` and later fallback to the string `'sid'`. You will get into trouble if there once really is a constant called `sid` defined.

Here, the corrected update statement in mysql library:

```
$sql = "UPDATE trans_vector SET sid='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['sid']) . "'";
```

Even better:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `trans_vector` SET `sid`='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['sid']) . "'";
```

Using backticks makes clear for MySQL that this is a **column name**. Sometimes you will have column names that are called like reserved keywords in SQL. Then you will **need** apostrophes. A common example is a column called `order` for the sequence of entries.